# Openlayers - Geoserver - tranforming srs of layers to match the base layer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have the following two layers and Open Street Map (OSM) layer. A part of the script is given below. My problem is when I view the results from the browser both the layers fall on a wrong coordinates. I think this is because they are originally ESPG 3006 but the base layer (OSM) is ESPG:3857. Now I want to transform the two layers to match with the base layer ESPG. Can i do this without using any GIS software? Please Help.

```
vagar_alla = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "vagar_alla", "http://localhost:8000/geoserver/myProject/wms",
                {
                    height: '489',
                    width: '512',
                    layers: 'myProject:vagar_alla',
                    styles: '',
                    srs: 'ESPG:3006',
                    format: 'image/png',
                    transparent:true,
                    tiled: 'true',
                    tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true

                } 
            );  
adresspt = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "adresspt", "http://localhost:8000/geoserver/myProject/wms",
    {
        height: '512',
        width: '458',
        layers: 'myProject:adresspt',
        styles: '',
        srs: 'ESPG:3006',
        format: 'image/png',
        tiled: 'true',
        transparent:true,
        tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom           
    },
    {
        buffer: 0,
        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true
    } 
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();     


    map.addLayers([osm,vagar_alla,adresspt]);
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line `srs: 'ESPG:3006',` OpenLayers will request the layer in the projection of the map (in your case epsg:3857) and GeoServer will reproject your layers to that projection before it sends them back (provided that you set the projection of your layers to 3006 correctly).

Comment: Thanks iant for your answer. I commented out the SRS lines but the two layers still fall somewhere else. Any other solution?

Comment: are you sure that they are stored in the correct project in GeoServer? Then check the log file to see if the reprojection is failing

Comment: also try taking out the tilesOrigin line so it's a plain WMS call